Azure Functions Timer Trigger Variable Fallback
When setting a timer trigger in azure functions, it is possible to set up the schedule using either a string directly, or as a variable. From the Microsoft Documentation:

You can put the schedule expression in an app setting and set this property to the app setting name wrapped in % signs, as %ScheduleAppSetting%.

So either:
[Function("Foo")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("1 1 * * *"] TimerInfo myTimer)

or
[Function("Foo")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%MyFooSchedule%"] TimerInfo myTimer)

Where MyFooSchedule is an Env variable.
If someone forgets to add this variable however, then this will never run, so is it possible to somehow have a default fallback schedule if this variable is missing?

To set a default value for an environment variable in an Azure Function if it's not provided, use a static constructor to check and set the default.
Here’s a simple example:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyFunctionApp
{
    public static class DataProcessingFunction
    {
        static DataProcessingFunction()
        {
            var defaultSchedule = "0 */5 * * * *"; // Every 5 minutes
            var schedule = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyFooSchedule") ?? defaultSchedule;
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MyFooSchedule", schedule);
        }

        [FunctionName("DataProcessingFunction")]
        public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%MyFooSchedule%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            await Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}

Handling Missing Configuration with Fallback Values in Azure Functions
